# Как динамически изменять текст при выборке из select?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<select>
   <option> one </option>
   <option> two </option>
   <option> three </option>
</select>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе `<option> one </option>` рядом появлялось число 1. И также самое со вторым, чтобы выводил 2.

Comment: То есть после выборки текст должно быть так: one 1, two 2, ...?

Comment: Ну, при выборе one должно появиться 1, а если потом выбрать two, то 1 исчезает и появляется 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант #1:

```js
$('div').html($('select option:selected').index()+1);
$('select').on('change',function(){
  $('div').html($('select option:selected').index()+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option> one </option>
   <option> two </option>
   <option> three </option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

Вариант #2:

```js
$('div').html($('select option:selected').attr('data-text'));
$('select').on('change',function(){
  $('div').html($('select option:selected').attr('data-text'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option data-text="1"> one </option>
   <option data-text="2"> two </option>
   <option data-text="3"> three </option>
</select>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
select.onchange = e => out.innerHTML = 1+select.selectedIndex;
```

```html
<select id='select'>
   <option> one </option>
   <option> two </option>
   <option> three </option>
</select>
<p id='out'></p>
```

Comment: Если запустить код и из списка сразу выбрать one не появляется 1

Comment: Потому что оно уже выбрано. Вы не можете запустить код и выбрать one